# Yii timepicker textbox size

Tags: php, jquery, yii

How can I change the default size of textbox for timepicker in Yii.
I'm using timepicker in Yii from the link [timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).

I have tried the htmlOptions , its now working,

```
$this->widget('application.extensions.timepicker.timepicker', 
    array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'name'=>'starttime',
        'select'=> 'time',
        'options' => array(
            'showOn'=>'focus',
            'timeFormat'=>'hh:mm:ss',
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                'size' => '10',         // textField size
                'maxlength' => '10',    // textField maxlength
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

what is the right way to set HTML options to the timepicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `htmlOptions` should not be inside the `options` array.

I'm using the Yii extension EJuiDateTimePicker (http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ejuidatetimepicker/) which is based on the same timepicker basically and there I can define the textfield size like this:

```
$this->widget('ext.timepicker.EJuiDateTimePicker', array(
        'model'=>new Report(),
        'name'=>'creation_date',
        'options' => array(
                'showOn'=>'focus',
                'timeFormat'=>'hh:mm:ss',
                'timeOnly'=>true,
        ),
        'htmlOptions' => array(
                'style'=>'width:150px;', // styles to be applied
                'maxlength' => '10',    // textField maxlength
        ),
));
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Did you use 'style' as well? 
Can you post the code of the actual extension, or at least a link to it? The link you posted is only the jQuery add on.

Comment: Just had a look. That extension does not provide support for htmlOptions at all! I suggest using the extension I'm using as that offers more features by the look of things.

Comment: mode => 'time' option is not working in EJuiDateTimePicker. what is the option to use only time picker

Comment: In the 'options' array add 'timeOnly'=>true, have updated my answer with it above.

Comment: See the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19000836/only-time-picker-in-ejuidatetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

> modify timepicker widget view file.there will be a size property.

```
<input type="text" class="timepicker" id="<?php echo $this->id; ?>" value="<?php echo $this->model->{$this->name}?$this->model->{$this->name}:$this->options['value']; ?>" name="<?php echo get_class($this->model).'['.$this->name.']'.$this->tabularLevel; ?>" size="15" />
```