# Only time picker in ejuidatetimepicker

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I'm using [ejuidatetimepicker](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ejuidatetimepicker/) in my Yii application. Its giving date and time picker.
I want only time picker, I have tried with two options `mode => 'time'` and `timeOnly=>true`. its not working.

Please find my below code.

```
   $this->widget( 'application.extensions.timepicker.EJuiDateTimePicker', array(
 'model' => $model, // Your model   
 'attribute' => 'starttime', // Attribute for input
 //'mode'=>'time', //Not working Error Message is "Property "EJuiDateTimePicker.mode" is not defined. "
 //timeOnly -  Default: false - Hide the datepicker and only provide a time interface.
  'timeOnly' => true, // Not working Error Message is "Property "EJuiDateTimePicker.timeOnly" is not defined."

 'options' => array(
  'showOn'=>'focus',
  'timeFormat'=>'hh:mm:ss',         
  'showSecond'=>true,  
  //'timeOnly' => true, // Not working Error Message is "Property "EJuiDateTimePicker.timeOnly" is not defined."

  ) ,                                       
 'htmlOptions' => array(                    
  'autocomplete' => 'off',                  
  'size' => 10,                     
  'maxlength' => 10,                        
  ),                                        
 ));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the option. We have to use

```
 'timePickerOnly' => 'true',
```

I have checked in EJuiDateTimePicker.php